# How to delete screen capture image in iPhone when application goes into background?

Tags: ios, background, home-button

When user press home button or if application goes into background due to any other reason, then iOS first take a screen shots and save it, I want to know location of that screen shot image and how can I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

We had same problem earlier. I am not sure where exactly it get stored. As far as I know, its not possible to delete that image.

But the solution we have applied is, we have just created a UIImageView of device screen size and added it to UIWindow in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method. When app becomes active, we are removing that UIImageView. We wrote that code in following method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried it. But I want to delete that captured image which save in device when home button pressed.